# mergepolicy on a to-one relationship with uniquing constraints erases object instead of updating it

Tags: core-data, merge, constraints, relationship

I've just encountered an odd Core Data behaviour. For context, my app consumes a JSON API by making my various Core Data entities decodable. Users can track TV Shows they're interested in so I have a `Show` entity with a to-many relationship to `Season`. The inverse is a to-one relationship since a season can only belong to a single TV show. I have a uniquing constraint on a `remoteID` property for both `Show` and `Season` entities.

At launch, I request updates on the user's TV shows. Due to the way I ingest the data, the JSON response essentially creates duplicates, then on save the `NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump` would ensure duplicates are merged thanks to the uniquing constraint.

This has been working fine for regular properties and to-many relationships but now that I'm syncing seasons, the to-one relationship deletes seasons with every other sync. For example:

Sync 1:

- `Show A` has 4 seasons locally.
- `Show A` is fetched with 4 seasons.
- After context is saved `Show A` now has 0 seasons

Sync 2:

- `Show A` now has 0 seasons locally.
- `Show A` is fetched with 4 seasons.
- After context is saved `Show A` now has 4 seasons

Note that if I set my inverse relationship to be to-many (from `Season` to `Show`), this behaviour does not happen. It's ok for my purposes but not ideal as it could create issues down the line.

This is my interpretation of what happens:

- Core Data first merges the duplicated `Season` objects.
- Because a `Season` can only have 1 `Show`, one of the duplicated `Show` will lose its link to that `Season`.
- Core Data then merges the duplicated `Show` objects.
- At that point, one of them has seasons and the other one doesn't.
- Core Data decides that the one without seasons is the most recent "change" and thus the one that should be committed to the store.

That last point I am unsure about and doesn't quite make sense to me. I guess my question is: does anyone knows precisely what is happening here and could confirm or correct my explanation? Also, if there's any way around it I don't know, I'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm facing the exact same issue with a coredata app myself at the moment and I've been banging my head against this wall for days...